# import HttpResponseRedirect in middleware

Tags: python, django, middleware

I've made a mobile service in django with the path prefix "/m/"
For redirect traffic from mobiles I've used middleware from here: http://blog.khmelyuk.com/2011/11/mobile-website-with-django.html.
I've completed this code by:

```
import re
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
```

And I've got a surprise:

```
NameError at /m/
global name 'HttpResponseRedirect' is not defined
```

WTF?

This is my middleware

```
class MobileWebsiteMiddleware(object):
    import re
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    MOBILE_PREFIX = '/m/'
    MOBI_REG = re.compile('(iphone|windowsce|mobile|phone|symbian|mini|pda|ipod|mobi|blackberry|playbook|vodafone|kindle)',
    re.IGNORECASE)

    def process_request(self, request):

        if 'HTTP_USER_AGENT' in request.META:
            userAgent = request.META.get('HTTP_USER_AGENT')
            matches = self.MOBI_REG.search(userAgent)
            path = request.path_info

            if matches:
            # from mobile browser, check if need to redirect to mobile
                if not path.startswith(self.MOBILE_PREFIX):
                # need to redirect to mobile version
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/m' + path)
            elif path.startswith(self.MOBILE_PREFIX):
                # need to redirect to normal version
                return HttpResponseRedirect(path[2:])
        return None
```

And this is the result:

```
NameError at /m/
global name 'HttpResponseRedirect' is not defined
...
Exception Location: /home/michal/.../detect_mobile.py in process_request, line 23
...
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'detect_mobile.MobileWebsiteMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
89. response = middleware_method(request)
File "/home/michal/django/christianitas_new/detect_mobile.py" in process_request
23. return HttpResponseRedirect(path[2:])
```

Comment: `django.http import from HttpResponseRedirect` this looks incorrect, is that the actual code?

Comment: Sure, I made mistake pasting it

Comment: It looks like a circular import problem.... what are other imports in this file ? Are you by any chance import this package in some other file and then importing * from that file ?

Comment: You should show some more of the context of the file, plus the complete traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a scope problem. For some reason, you're importing that name at the class level, but Python does not define a scope for classes, so your method cannot see it. There's no reason to put the import there, though: put it at the top of the file, with all the other imports.